# Create two task in C# .net and close one of them after specific period of time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, thread-synchronization

I have a method which sometimes takes more than a minute to execute. I want to create a task to monitor the time it takes to execute this method. If the method executes with-in 2 minute, I should return output of the first task else I should throw an exception. I am using .net framework 4.0 with C# as the language.

I cannot use [Microsoft Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) in this case, as it frees the main thread. 
I do not want to release the main thread until following happens

1. Timeout
2. Data is returned
3. Any other exception occurs

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should use `CancellationTokenSource` with timeout and observe its `CancellationToken` inside your method. If that's not possible, you can use `Task.WhenAny`. The following implementation of `MethodAsync` should suit your scenario for .NET 4.0:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        // the method to monitor and timeout
        int Method()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000); // sleep for 3s
            return 42;
        }

        Task<int> MethodAsync(int timeout)
        {
            // start the Method task
            var task1 = Task.Run(() => Method());

            // start the timeout task
            var task2 = Task.Delay(timeout);

            // either task1 or task2
            return Task.WhenAny(task1, task2).ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                if (task.Result == task1)
                    return task1.Result;
                throw new TaskCanceledException();
            });
        }

        // The entry of the console app
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // timeout in 6s
                int result = new Program().MethodAsync(6000).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the version of `MethodAsync` using `async/await`, if you can use [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async):

```
async Task<int> MethodAsync(int timeout)
{
    // start the Method task
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => Method());

    // start the timeout task
    var task2 = Task.Delay(timeout);

    // either task1 or task2
    var task = await TaskEx.WhenAny(task1, task2);
    if (task == task1)
        return task1.Result;

    throw new TaskCanceledException();
}
```

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite, you have a number of options: **1)** just call it like this: `var result = MethodAsync(timeout: 1000).Result;` - this will block the main thread. **2)** alternatively: `MethodAsync(timeout: 1000).Wait();` **3)** remove `async/await` and do `Task.WaitAny` instead of `TaskEx.WhenAny` inside the code I posted.

Comment: I executed the code you shared after making these two changes. 1) Sleep period for task 1 is set to 3000 & task 2 is set as 6000. But task 2 is getting executed first and it is resulting in TaskCanceledException –

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite, indeed there was an obscure bug in the `ContinueWith` version, note the change: `task.Result == task1`. Try it now. The `async/await` version didn't have that bug.

Comment: What if the MethodAsync() does not return any result. when I tried option 2 suggested by you "MethodAsync(timeout: 1000).Wait();" System is unable to recognize wait()

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite, in this case, the signature of the method should be just `Task MethodAsync(int timeout)`. Note it was `Task<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. It would be super easy.

Here it is:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Start(() => longRunningTask())
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0));
```

You then just subscribe to the observable to get the result out.

```
query.Subscribe(
    n => Console.WriteLine(n),
    ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));
```

That's it. You either get the result out - the `n` - or you get the exception - the `ex`. Simple as that. And it's all run in a background task for you.

---

Use this kind of code to have the long-running computation complete on timeout.

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Create<int>(o =>
            Scheduler.Default.AsLongRunning().ScheduleLongRunning(c =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    if (c.IsDisposed)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!c.IsDisposed)
                {
                    o.OnNext(42);
                }
                o.OnCompleted();
            }))
        .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0));
```

The key thing to understand with Rx is that cancellation is all based on the `IDisposable` interface. In fact the `Subscribe` method returns an `IDisposable` that allows the subscribing code to early terminate an Rx subscription. But when an observable completes (either with an `OnComplete` or `OnError` then the underlying disposable is disposed. When there are a chain of operators then every disposable in the chain are disposed.

So this code returns merely returns a disposable that once disposed will terminate the computation. Quite simple really.

Comment: With RX, will `longRunningTask` continue executing anyway upon timeout? I imagine it will, it would take something like `Thread.Abort()` to stop it, right?

Comment: @avo - You are right. Rx doesn't stop the background task. It cleanly ignores the result, but won't stop the code. This makes sense as it has know way to know what aborting the thread will do to your program. It may be half-way through doing a write operation for example. The code needs to be written to be aware that it should terminate. I'll add an example bit of code that will properly complete.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thank you for reply. But using Microsoft Reactive extensions would release the main thread. It will not wait for timeout or it will not wait for method to return actual data. It The solution is not suitable for my problem.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite - Ah, I thought the point of using to tasks was to free the main thread. You could always add `.First()` to the end of the observable to make the main thread wait for the result.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yes, I want to  free the main thread but only when - either the task 1 is finished or task 2 gets timedout. I will try using ".First()" at the end of observable. Thank you for your help and reply. I have already chosen the answer but I will up-vote your answer :) And thank you for introducing Rx to me :)

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite - Careful! Once you get started with Rx you won't want to stop using it. It'll replace TPL for you without any issues. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TimeOut` class that you use to throw a `TimeoutException` after a given time. Something like:

```
const int twoMinutes = 120000;
TimeOutHelper.ExecuteMethod(() =>
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int c = -1;

    do
    {
        c = Service.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
    } while (c == 0);

}, twoMinutes);
```

Code:

```
public  static class TimeOutHelper
{
    private class ObjectState
    {
        public Action predict { get; set; }
        public AutoResetEvent autoEvent { get; set; }
    }

    public static bool ExecuteMethod(Action predict, int timeOutInterval, int retryCounter = 1)
    {
        bool IsFinished = false;
        ObjectState objectState = new ObjectState();
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        int timeOutInt = timeOutInterval > 0 ? timeOutInterval: Timeout.Infinite;
        objectState.autoEvent = autoEvent;
        objectState.predict = predict;
        Timer timer = null;

        var callbackMethod = new TimerCallback(TimerCallbackMethod);
        timer = new Timer(callbackMethod, objectState, 0, timeOutInt+5);

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < retryCounter; i++)
            {
                var isSignal = autoEvent.WaitOne(timeOutInt, false);
                if (isSignal)
                 break; 
                if (retryCounter - 1 == i) throw new TimeoutException();
                else
                    timer.Change(0, timeOutInt);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            IsFinished = true;

            if (autoEvent != null)
                autoEvent.Dispose();
            if (timer != null)
                timer.Dispose();
        }
        return IsFinished;
    }

    private static void TimerCallbackMethod(object state)
    {
        var objectSate = (ObjectState)state;
        var predict = (Action)objectSate.predict;
        predict();
        if(objectSate!=null && !objectSate.autoEvent.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed)
            objectSate.autoEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use timer as thread.

```
System.Threading.Timer timer;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Module_Watchdog), null, 0, 1000);
```

Module_Watchdog() executes at specified intervals(1000 ms here). Note that Module_Watchdog() does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.

```
private void Module_Watchdog(object obj)
{
   // Block here output of task1 as timeout already occured..
   try
   {
   throw new TimeoutException();
   }
   finally
   {

   }
}
```

and final implementation will be like this:

```
...
...
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Module_Watchdog), null, 0, 1000);
Moduleunder_Watchdog();
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite); //disable
```

you can also in runtime modify timings, if your code have find that it will be taking more time to process

```
 timer.Change(0, 1000); //enable
```

if you need to read the value of time taken you can use stopwatch.
More information on the stopwatch could be at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx